# Significance of using the term "over" when talking about operations

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Here is an example sentence which uses the term "***over***" when talking abut a type and one of its operations:-

> "*A monoid is a type along with an associative binary operation **over** it...*"

My question is not about monoids - what I don't quite understand is the use of the term "***over***".

Is this from mathematics?
Does it mean that the operation works on the data defined by the type itself - as opposed to any data we might pass to it from outside the instance of that type?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it comes from Math.
In Math and FP, unlike OOP, data structures are defined independently from functions that operate on this structure. 
As a consequence it's easy to have many different operations over the same data type. For example Sum monoid over Intergers and Multiplication monoid over Integers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But why "over" rather than "on" which is the usual way we describe applying an operation to data.